# React Router v4. Route not visible.

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I was using `router v3` and started refactoring the routing logic according to `v4` in order to further implement `transition-groups` and came up with the following code. There is no error in while compiling or in the console, when I go to the `/#/about` it returns an empty page.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Store from './container/store/store';
import Container from './container/container';


const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');

const render = () => {
  const store = Store({});

  ReactDOM.render(
      <Container store={store} />,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};


// Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./routes/index', () =>
    setImmediate(() => {
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
      render();
    })
    // This method is used to break up long running operations and run a callback function immediately after the browser has completed other operations such as events and display updates.
  );
};

render();
```

**container.js (hooks up redux to the application)**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


// Wrap
import Wrap from '../wrap';
import Contact from '../routes/contact';


export default class Container extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Wrap}/>
          </Switch>
          </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**wrap.js (works as index route)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/header';
import styles from './styles/styles.css';
import { HashRouter, Switch, Redirect, Route, BrowserRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import About from '../routes/about';


export default class Wrap extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header location={this.props.location} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
        ... other stuff
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `exact` in your `<Route path='/' />`.

`exact` will only render the component with the given path.

Comment: thank you a lot for the explanation, work like a charm :)